# How to connect MTS MBlaze

Tags: 11.04, wireless, networking

i have installed ubuntu 11.04 inside the windows xp. i have MTS Mblaze USB Modem. (my service provider is MTS MBlaze,india) i want to use Mblaze into ubuntu so that i did the following steps for make connecting the device.

```
from the task bar->edit connections->mobile broadband->choose country->mts mblaze and ok

i give username and password (internet@internet.mtsindia.in and password MTS. ok

now i enable mobile broadband , MTS MBlaze connection1(connection name) from task bar.
```

steps followed from "**http://randomshandom.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/how-to-connect-mts-mblaze-device-in-ubuntu-10-10-11-04/#more-3**"

for the first time it successfully connected and browse the internet. after i restart the system i connect it. it does not connected. it shows Modem network disconnected. i accessed many times and delete the connection and recreated but i does not help me. if i try to connect device i think it the search the network, i saw the wave signal. img[image]

Image for showing problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

hi there from the description I see that u run natty in virtual machine. just clarify whether the usb modem is configured in the devices of the virtual box and make sure that connect automatically is ticked on.if it doesn't work start delete the connection and start from the start

Comment: From the screenshot it is clear that it is ubuntu 11.10

Install inside may refer to the wubi installation

Comment: ya i missed revamped power cog sorry!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed ubuntu inside windows using virtual box .just connect to internet using driver provided by mts

If you installed in a separate partition  and experiancing this problem use wvdial

if you installed it in wubi connect to internet from windows and restart then chose ubuntu (I dont know what is actually happens ,but this trick works atleast for me)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://github.com/Trixarian/sakis3g-source) code, Now i can connect to my mobile broadband .

- Checkout the source code, and follow the `Compiling` ,`Running` instructions.